# Android call component w/listener or have the viewmodel call the component communicate withe the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm

I am calling a signin method from a fragment using a viewmodel. I have been using a lot of callbacks in other areas but [read](https://medium.com/@pawardeepakv/google-play-console-internal-test-c6e4ea369ed8) that using MVVM I should not be communicating between the fragment and the viewmodel in this way. The Android documentation seems to use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) as well. Why is it ok to have listeners for components like adapters for recyclerview and not other components which are called from a view model.

The signin component is in the Splash fragment. Should I call it as a component outside the viewmodel and take advantage of the listeners?

I'm running into an error and want to give feedback to the user. Do I:

1. Take the component out of the viewmodel and call it directly from the fragment
2. Leave the component in the viewmodel and provide the feedback to the fragment/user by utilizing livedata?
3. Leave the signin component in the viewmodel and just use a callback/listener

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the feedback. I will provide more detail. I'm using Java, FYI. I am focused on the first run procedure, which is different from displaying a list or detail data. So, I need to have a lot of things happen to get the app ready for first use, and I need a lot of feedback in case things go wrong. I created a splash screen and have a way to record the steps in the process, so I can tell when something goes wrong, where it goes wrong. The user ends up seeing the last message, but the complete message is saved.

I have been adding a listener to the call and an interface to the component. If you haven't guessed, I'm somewhat of a novice, but this seemed to really be a good pattern, but I have been reading this is not the right way to communicate between the Fragment and the ViewModel.

Example, from the SplashFragment.java:

```
viewModel.signIn(getActivity(), getAuthHelperSignInCallback());
```

In the SplashViewModel.java:

```
public void signIn (Activity activity, AuthHelper.AuthHelperSignInListener listener) {
    
     AuthHelper authHelper = new AuthHelper(activity.getApplication());
     authHelper.signIn(activity,listener);
}
```

In the AuthHelper.java I have an interface:

```
public interface AuthHelperSignInListener {
     void onSuccess(IAuthenticationResult iAuthenticationResult);
     void onCancel();
     void onError(MsalException e);
}
```

Using this method I can get information back that I need, so if I'm not supposed to use a callback/listener in the fragment like this, what is the alternative?

Comment: **I have been using a lot of callbacks in other areas but read that using MVVM I should not be communicating between the fragment and the viewmodel in this way.**  What do you mean by this way here?

Comment: Are you asking, what is the best practice to trigger a UI event, like showing an error `alert`, `toast` or `snackbar` from `viewmodel`?

Comment: No. I created a signin method in the viewmodel which calls a component to sign in. The component requires a listener/interface, which has a complete and error callback. Everything happens in the view model but I think I need to callback to the fragment so I can display the error to the user. I read that this is not the right MVVM approach and I should use LiveData w/observers. It just seems like I might end up with a lot of observers for errors if I have a few of components.

Comment: I am assuming I should not call UI components from the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `channel` to send these events to your activity or fragment, and trigger UI operation accordingly. `Channel` belongs to `kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel` package.

First, create these events in your `viewModel` class using a `sealed class`.

```
sealed class SignInEvent{
    data class ShowError(val message: String) : SignInEvent()
    data class ShowLoginSuccess(val message: String) : SignInEvent()
}
```

Define a `channel` variable inside `viewModel`.

```
private val signInEventChannel = Channel<SignInEvent>()
   
// below flow will be used to collect these events inside activity/fragment
val signInEvent = signInEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()
```

Now you can send any `error` or `success` event from `viewModel`, using the defined event channel

```
fun onSignIn() {
     try {
          //your sign in logic
          
          // on success
          signInEventChannel.send(SignInEvent.ShowLoginSuccess("Login successful"))
     } catch(e: Exception){
          //on getting an error.
          signInEventChannel.send(SignInEvent.ShowError("There is an error logging in"))
     }         
}
```

Now you can listen to these events and trigger any UI operation accordingly, like showing a toast or a snackbar

In activity

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        activityViewModel.signInEvent.collect { event ->
                when (event) {
                    //ActivityViewModel is your viewmodel's class name
                    is ActivityViewModel.SignInEvent.ShowError-> {
                        Snackbar.make(binding.root, event.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                    is ActivityViewModel.SignInEvent.ShowLoginSuccess-> {
                        Snackbar.make(binding.root, event.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                }
}
```

In fragment

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        fragmentViewModel.signInEvent.collect { event ->
                when (event) {
                    is FragmentViewModel.SignInEvent.ShowError-> {
                        Snackbar.make(requireView(), event.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                    is FragmentViewModel.SignInEvent.ShowLoginSuccess-> {
                        Snackbar.make(requireView(), event.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Praveen. I happen to be using Java, which I should have stated in the original post. Would I use a Channel in java as well?

Comment: @lcj `Channel` belong to `kotlin` `coroutines`, they aren't available in `java`.

Comment: For your use case in java, you can create different live data for your sign-in states and observe them individually, because you have to pass your success result or error. You could've also used `enum` if there won't have been any result.

Comment: I like it, codewise is almost the same as having multiple livedatas or flows in the VM but it looks more like a contract which needs to be implemented rather than subscribing to known stateholders